# Unable to get CRL from valid certificate

Tags: openssl, ssl-certificate, x509certificate

I have a working certificate but can't get the CRL info from it for some reason.

I ran this to make sure it is working:

```
openssl x509 -outform PEM -in cert_2_.pem
```

And here is the output:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Then I tried to get the CRL with:

```
openssl x509 -outform PEM -in cert_2_.pem | openssl crl -text
```

But this was the output

```
unable to load CRL
140537848063680:error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line:pem_lib.c:703:Expecting: X509 CRL
```

Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: Related from [Super User](http://superuser.com): [s_client not failing on revoked certifcate?](http://superuser.com/questions/742231/s-client-not-failing-on-revoked-certifcate).

Comment: X509 certificates have CRL distribution points, not a built-in CRL. The distibution point tells you where to go the get the CRL.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You did not download the CRL. All you did was encode the certificate to PEM format. Then you tried to pipe the output of cert PEM encoding to openssl where you instructed openssl to treat it like a CRL.

You could parse certificate using

```
openssl x509 -in cert_2_.pem -text
```

Then manually or with help of some other command (like grep, awk or something) parse out the url where CRL is being published.

Then you could dowload the CRL using wget.

Finally you could parse the crl using the command

```
openssl crl -in downloaded.crl -text
```